# CMake search for shared libraries in relative path

Tags: c++, cmake, rpath

Is there a way to specify the shared library path from CMakeLists.txt?
I want to make an executable which uses OpenCV but I don't want the final user to install OpenCV. Instead I would like to deliver a folder containing my executable and the shared libraries it needs. The final structure should be something like

Delivery

- MyApp
- OpenCV (folder containing opencv dylibs)

In the end MyApp should search for the shared libs in OpenCV folder.
I tried to use the info from https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling but for some reason I don't seem to understand what i really have to do to achieve what I want.

I tried to set CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH to @loader_path or @executable_path but don't see any change. It still searches for opencv libs in /lib folder.

Running otool -L MyApp results in:

lib/libopencv_imgproc.3.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.1.0, current version 3.1.0)
lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.1.0, current version 3.1.0)
lib/libopencv_highgui.3.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.1.0, current version 3.1.0)
lib/libopencv_core.3.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.1.0, current version 3.1.0)

/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)

/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)

Comment: Is there any reason to provide OpenCV header files in your installation? Using the link you pointed, what have you tried so far (edit your post with a minimal example and what goes wrong)?

Comment: You are right. Only OpenCV dylibs should be delivered. I updated the original post.